# In my example, did I use brackets correctly?

Tags: parentheses

I know the rules of this site state to only ask questions to get direct answers, but I'm hoping I could still get a little suggestion on what to do. I'm writing a research paper, so the context is formal writing. I'm revising the last section of my abstract. And please, if brackets do not seem essential in my case, let me know :)

Here are the original two sentences I want to combine:

> Due to the nature of this study, I used the instrumental variables (IV) approach to estimate the effect of the MLDA on mortality in terms of per person drinking. Through careful analysis I believe the IV assumptions are met, which implies that the IV estimate shows the causal effect of the MLDA on mortality in terms of per person drinking.

This is how I intend to combine them by using some form of brackets:

> Due to the nature of this study, I used the instrumental variables (IV) approach — and through the IV assumptions — to estimate the causal effect of the MLDA on mortality in terms of per person drinking.

Comment: I don't think you can telescope your original wording to the extent you want to without changing the meaning considerably. I would retain the first sentence of the original version as you wrote it and alter the second to say something like this: "If (as I believe after careful analysis) the IV assumptions are met, the IV estimate shows the causal effect of the MLDA on mortality, expressed in terms of per person drinking."

Comment: If you replace the dashes with commas, you will see why this doesn't work: "I used the instrumental variables (IV) approach and, through the IV assumptions, to estimate..." does not make sense. The parenthetical section should match the main clause grammatically and syntactically. It seems like you are trying to say "I used the instrumental variables (IV) approach and - using the IV assumptions - estimated..." (although the dashes are quite abrupt; commas would be fine), but this doesn't seem to mean quite the same thing as the original text. I think it needs more clarifying text.

Comment: I don't understand why you're talking about brackets—the only brackets in either version of your sentence are the ones in “(IV)”, and those are obviously correct. Did you mean _dashes_?

Answer (score 1):

As both comments note, your second example isn't very successful at combining the two sentences. If your goal is simply to avoid repeating the phrase "effect of the MLDA on mortality in terms of per person drinking" you can just eliminate its second use:

> Due to the nature of this study, I used the instrumental variables (IV) approach to estimate the effect of the MLDA on mortality in terms of per person drinking. Through careful analysis I believe the IV assumptions are met, which implies that the IV estimate shows the causal effect.

Alternatively, you can eliminate the first use:

> Due to the nature of this study, I used the instrumental variables (IV) approach to estimate the effect. Through careful analysis I believe the IV assumptions are met, which implies that the IV estimate shows the causal effect of the MLDA on mortality in terms of per person drinking.